# WEKA - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error when using the api

Tags: java, weka

I have used `FilteredClassifier` to create a model. Now I want to evaluate the model on a test set. 
I can do this through the GUI, but when using the API, my java program creates an error when it tries to call `classifyInstance()` method.

Below are the test file, java program and error message I receive

### Test file:

> @relation train-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R2-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-C1
>
> @attribute QUOTE string 
>   @attribute CAT {Art,Beauty,Love,Life,Knowledge,Truth,Best,Strength,Great,Friendship,Hope,Power,Funny}
>
> @data 
>   'True art is characterized by an irresistible urge in the creative artist.',?

### Java code:

```
public class test { 

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                String fileName = "./tree.model"; 
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)); 
                Object tmp = in.readObject(); 
                FilteredClassifier tree = (FilteredClassifier) tmp; 
                in.close(); 
                System.out.println("===== Loaded model: " + fileName + " ====="); 


                // load unlabeled data 
                Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./test3.arff"))); 


                 System.out.println(unlabeled); 

                 // set class attribute 
                 unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1); 

                 // create copy 
                 Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled); 

                 // label instances 
                 for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) { 
                   double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i)); 
                   labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel); 
                 } 
                 // save labeled data 
                 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/some/where/labeled.arff")); 
                 writer.write(labeled.toString()); 
                 writer.newLine(); 
                 writer.flush(); 
                 writer.close(); 
        } 
}
```

### Error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) 
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) 
        at weka.core.Instances.attribute(Instances.java:341) 
        at weka.core.AttributeLocator.locate(AttributeLocator.java:153) 
        at weka.core.AttributeLocator.initialize(AttributeLocator.java:119) 
        at weka.core.AttributeLocator.<init>(AttributeLocator.java:102) 
        at weka.core.StringLocator.<init>(StringLocator.java:69) 
        at weka.filters.Filter.flushInput(Filter.java:431) 
        at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector.batchFinished(StringToWordVector.java:768) 
        at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.filterInstance(FilteredClassifier.java:474) 
        at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.distributionForInstance(FilteredClassifier.java:495) 
        at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:70) 
        at test.main(test.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unlabeled.instance(0)
```

seems to be empty that is the reason you are getting this exception

Comment: I dont think it's empty cause if I use:
    System.out.println(unlabeled.instance(0));
it printout the data line:
'True art is characterized by an irresistible urge in the creative artist.',?

Comment: @user1850632 : which line are you getting the error? is that labeled.instance(i)? apart from this i dont see you accessing the index to cause the out of bounds exception? unless i am missing something

Comment: double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i)) line cause the error. if I remove the for loop and change the line to:
double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(0))
I still get the same error